# Im not sure why this code works I understand everything except for the line self._first = self._first.next why does this line remove the first element

Tags: python, list, linked-list

I have a working program that removes the first element of a linked list.
I'm not sure why the line self._first = self._first.next removes the first element of the list. Can someone please clarify it for me?

```
 def remove_first(self) -> Any:
       
        curr = self._first
        if curr is None:
            raise IndexError
        else:
            first = curr.item
            self._first = self._first.next
            return first
```

Comment: It assigns the next element of the current first element as the new first element.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why it deletes the first item from a linked list lets say i had a linked list that was [1,2,3] it would turn it into [2.3]

Comment: Harun answered your question in a comment but why are you implementing linked lists yourself in Python? There are many ready-made efficient data structures in the standard library that can handle pretty much any scenario where a linked list could make sense.

Comment: Im implementing it myself because my school is requiring it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your linked list is implemented like this:

`List .first --> Item #1 .next ---> Item#2 .next --> Item#3` etc

The code reassigns the `.first` member variable of the `List` class to point to `Item#2`. Thus if you iterate through the list starting from `.first` the `Item#1` is no longer "in the list". It also decrements the refcount for `Item#1` which will deallocate it when refcount goes to zero.